# Problems with list inside lists

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have been having problems with a sub navigation menu I have been creating using css and html.

The problem is that the third level navigation is displaying inline when I want it to display as a list. What would be the best way to have this displaying as a list?

Everything I do does not seem to work think it may be an issue with css clashing.

I have included a jsfiddle and code.

https://jsfiddle.net/e52u02bL/

```
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="nav">
<ul class="nav-primary test">
    <li><a href="#">Household</a>
        <ul class="test">
            <li><a href="#">Living Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bedroom</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Living Room</a>
                <ul>
                    <div><h4>Heading</h4></div>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hardware</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Wedding List</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>

CSS

    .nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position:relative;
}

.nav ul {
  background: #FFF;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.test li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li a {
  color:#333333;
  display:block;
  padding:0px 40px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  background: #3B95D3;
}


.nav ul li:hover > a{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

.nav ul ul {
background: #FFF;
padding:0;
display:none;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0px;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
background: #3B95D3;
display:none;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0px;
}

.nav ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
float:left;
background-color:red;
padding-top:;
width: 33.33333%;
}

.nav ul ul ul li {
display: block;
}

div > h4 {color:#FFF; padding-left: 38px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    padding: 0 2em;
}

.nav ul {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean could you elaborate more?

Comment: Would this be causing the error of not allowing the list below it to display as a list rather than inline?

Comment: It's inline because of two things: `.nav ul li a {float: left;}` and `ul.test li {display: inline-block;}`.

Comment: I now see that @Neps mentioned this already but I modified your fiddle a bit to do what you may be looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this new fiddle. Its rough to what you may need but you can tweak the width and insert an li header. Don't use a div as a direct descendent of ul.

[new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e52u02bL/3/)

```
.nav ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  float:left; <-- this is one of your main problems.
  background-color:red;
  padding-top:;
  width: 33.33333%;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant thank you thats the solution I needed that sorted the problem out!

Comment: Might be to do with the way it has been coded but I was planning to add more categories to the right in the window that opens up when I do this at the moment doesn't seem to display it any reason for this?